# Centering annotation in window/view

Tags: dm-script

If I have a 4k image displayed in DM and have zoomed into a certain area, how can I add an annotation that appears in the middle of the window and not somewhere outside where I can't see it?

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

> You need to first get the visible rect of the ImageDocument and then
>   convert the View-coordinates into Image-Coordinates. The following
>   script does this:

```
void GetWindowRectInImageCoordinates( image img, number &wt, number &wl, number &wb, number &wr )
{
    imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
    imageDocument doc = img.ImageGetorCreateImageDocument()

    number t,l,b,r
    doc.ImageDocumentGetVisibleViewRect(t,l,b,r)

    number C2V_ox, C2V_oy, C2V_sx, C2V_sy
    disp.ComponentGetChildToViewTransform(C2V_ox, C2V_oy, C2V_sx, C2V_sy)

    wt = (t - C2V_oy) / C2V_sy
    wl = (l - C2V_ox) / C2V_sx
    wb = (b - C2V_oy) / C2V_sy
    wr = (r - C2V_ox) / C2V_sx
}

image img := GetFrontImage()
number tN, lN, bN, rN
GetWindowRectInImageCoordinates( img, tN, lN, bN, rN )

// Add a circle
number cX = (lN+rN)/2
number cY = (tN+bN)/2
number r = min(bN-tN,rN-lN)/10
component centerCycle = NewOvalAnnotation( cY-R,cX-R,cY+R,cX+R)
centerCycle.ComponentSetForeGroundColor(0.2,0.2,0.2)
centerCycle.ComponentSetBackGroundColor(1,0,0)
centerCycle.ComponentSetFillMode(2)
centerCycle.ComponentSetDrawingMode(1)
img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ComponentAddChildAtEnd( centerCycle )
```